# Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: from gcp ubuntu

Tags: opencv, google-cloud-platform, tcp, cloud, ubuntu-18.04

We are doing tcp communication. It was possible to send and receive messages. I tried to send and receive pictures through opencv, but an error occurred. Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: I tried a lot to fix this error, but couldn't find an answer. Currently, I have configured the cloud with Ubuntu. Is it impossible to display photos by receiving photos from Google Cloud?

Comment: Please let me know what have you already tried to fix this issue. Does [this](https://superuser.com/questions/310197/how-do-i-fix-a-cannot-open-display-error-when-opening-an-x-program-after-sshi) answer your question?

Comment: It was solved by using the gui environment. Thank you.
But now it's a yolo problem.
Local recognition is normal, but gcp does not. Do you know how to fix it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67422601/yolov4-does-not-work-properly-with-google-cloud-platform

this is my new question