# yolov4 does not work properly with google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, vnc, yolov4

Yolov4 works fine on the local computer.
I ran it on ubuntu using google cloud platform, but
Object recognition is not possible.
All environments required for ubuntu have been built.
I am using yolo-v4 using only numpy and opencv.
When I run it on ubuntu-18.04-LTS of gcp, the screen is printed well, but the object is not recognized. The path names of the weight file and cfg file are entered normally, and no error occurs. However, object recognition is not performed. I am using TIGERVNC for GUI environment. Is there a solution?

Comment: Have you tried enabling Display device settings? it may help to improve your situation: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/enable-instance-virtual-display#virtual-display-create

Comment: Thank you. I'll try. But I tried putting in a video file, and object recognition didn't work. Good on the local computer, but no object recognition in the cloud.